# Best practice to get only one related item (1:n) based on conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables, something like this:

**products** (id, name)

**coupons** (id, product_id*, value, starting, expiring)

... and with my JSON API I want to return all products. If there is a valid active coupon now this should be returned too.

At the moment I only get this JSON-result:

```
[{
 id: 1,
 name: 'A',
 coupons: [
  { ...},
  { ...},
]
}]
```

But I want to get something like this:

```
[{
 id: 1,
 name: 'A',
 coupon: { ...}
}]
```

I could "preprocess" the result of my query in the controller and set the coupon-attribute manually. But maybe there is a smarter way to solve this? Could I implement a coupon() function in the Product-model which handles this?

**Edit:**

Now this model made my code a little bit cleaner:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

    public function activeCoupons() {
        $instance = $this->hasMany('App\Models\Coupon', 'dish_id');
        $instance->getQuery()->where('start', '<', new \DateTime());
        $instance->getQuery()->where('end', '>', new \DateTime());
        return $instance;
    }
}
```

But now, I need to set manually

```
$product['coupon'] = $product->activeCoupons[0]
```

Is it possible that the function activeCoupon(s) of the model returns not a array? It should return only one object (not one object in an array).

Answer (score 3):

if you have only one coupon attached to each product
in model

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\coupons');
}

public function coupons()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\products');
}
```

and in controller

```
   public function allProducts(){
      $products = products::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->with('coupons')->get();
      return $products 
   }
```

Comment: No, that would be easy. The problem is, that there are more than one coupon attached to a product, but only one can be active at one time (because of the starting, expiring date).

Comment: May be your product could have 'hasOne' relation to the only active coupon, whose status is 'active' , then it would be possible. And hasMany relation to all coupons